# How to make a variable into a true or false statement

Tags: jquery

How can i enable / disable each or all of these 3 variables , so i can use the same script on all pages, but decide if i want 1 , 2 or 3 of the varibles set to true or false.

https://jsfiddle.net/zqu3eqfm/364/

```
var donotcountP = ':has(.warning):contains(P)';
var donotcountS = ':has(.warning):contains(S)';
var donotcountO = ':has(.warning):contains(O)';

$('.two_column_layout').find("td.player:not("+donotcountP+"):not("+donotcountS+"):not("+donotcountO+")").css('background', 'red');
```

Comment: I would like to be able to set var donotCountP = true or false;  , and have that enable/disable the script to use :has(.warning):contains(P) within it

Comment: try using length property, if length>0?true:false;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it this way (untested code - and for better code quality you probably want to extract another method for the if-loops):

```
var donotcountP = true;
var donotcountS = false;
var donotcountO = true;

var getPlayerQuery = function() {
    var result = "td.player";
    if(donotcountP) {
        result = result + ":not(':has(.warning):contains(P)')";
    }
    if(donotcountS) {
        result = result + ":not(':has(.warning):contains(S)')";
    }
    if(donotcountO) {
        result = result + ":not(':has(.warning):contains(O)')";
    }
    return result;
}


$('.two_column_layout').find(getPlayerQuery()).css('background', 'red');
```

Comment: ok got it working if i place the var getPlayerQuery above the function

Comment: great, thanks for the note, made an edit to the awnser